# Trouble working with Androidx FileProvider Protected Constructors

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I am working on an app that downloads and organizes PDFs. I would like to create a URI such that an intent can open one of the downloaded PDFs. I am having trouble generating and using URIs using the FileProvider framework.

I have found two general guides for how to implement the FileProvider functionality. The first is to add the following to my manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="uk.co.section9.zotdroid.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

The paths XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external" path="/"
        />
</paths>
```

And using the following in my Intent code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
File ff7 = new File(filepath);

if (ff7.exists()) {
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to open " + filwpath);
    try {
        Uri pdfURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                "uk.co.section9.zotdroid.provider",
                ff7);
        intent.setDataAndType(pdfURI, filetype);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _download_dialog.dismiss();
        startActivity(intent);
        _download_dialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error opening file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    _main_list_view.invalidate();
    _main_list_view.invalidateViews();
    _main_list_view.refreshDrawableState();

} else {
    String status_message = "Error: " + filepath + " does not appear to exist.";
    TextView messageView = (TextView) _download_dialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewDownloading);
    messageView.setText(status_message);
    Log.i(TAG, status_message);
}
```

When using this method, an OS dialogue will open asking me which PDF viewer I would like to use, but the PDF viewer always crashes or otherwise fails. I will sometimes get the following stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: content://uk.co.section9.zotdroid.provider/external/ZotDroid/filename.pdf
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:2020)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1849)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1525)
at com.samsung.android.support.senl.nt.base.common.util.UriFileUtils.saveUriToFile(Unknown Source:30)
at com.samsung.android.support.senl.nt.base.common.util.UriFileUtils.saveUriToFile(Unknown Source:29)
at com.samsung.android.support.senl.nt.base.common.util.ContentPickerUtils.downloadFile(Unknown Source:119)
at com.samsung.android.support.senl.nt.base.common.util.ContentPickerUtils.downloadPdf(Unknown Source:30)
at com.samsung.android.support.senl.nt.composer.main.base.presenter.task.TaskAddPdf.downloadPdf(Unknown Source:16)
at com.samsung.android.support.senl.nt.composer.main.base.presenter.task.TaskAddPdf.downloadPdfList(Unknown Source:94)
at com.samsung.android.support.senl.nt.composer.main.base.presenter.task.TaskAddPdf.access$600(Unknown Source:0)
at com.samsung.android.support.senl.nt.composer.main.base.presenter.task.TaskAddPdf$1.run(Unknown Source:81)
```

I have searched for this issue, but I cannot find an answer on how to fix it.

The second method I have used comes from [Google's own tutorial](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider), where you define your own FileProvider. The manifest is thus modified:

```
<provider
            android:name="uk.co.section9.zotdroid.ZotFileProvider"
            android:authorities="uk.co.section9.zotdroid.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

and a java file is created that looks like this:

```
package uk.co.section9.zotdroid;

import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

public class ZotFileProvider extends FileProvider {
    public ZotFileProvider() {
        super(R.xml.file_paths);
    }
}
```

This does not compile, as the super constructor will only accept 0 arguments. Looking into this, it appears that the FileProvider constructor that accepts this argument is protected. Unfortunately, everything I have found online says that I should be able to access it, which is not very helpful.

I am stuck. I do not know why either of these things are happening, and there has been no useful resources online. I would appreciate any guidance as to how I can get a working URI.

Comment: What is ff7? Also show the xml file. Show also complete intent creation.

Comment: They have been added

Comment: `File ff7 = new File(filepath);` We dont know what path that would be. Put it in your code. Start with it. Show what you do. Also use ff7.canRead() before you try to create an intent.

Comment: You should not call setFlags() twice as the last one will erase all that was before. You lost the READ flag now.

Comment: The issue was canread, I did not have the file permissions (this is me trying to resurrect the open source app ZotDroid and I figured I would get around to remaking permission handling later. Seems like that was a bad idea lmao). Thank you for your help @blackapps

Comment: Same problem 1.5 years later. Does Google test the code published in the docs??